# iOS AudioQueueNewInput function - how to link it in?

Tags: audiotoolbox

I am trying to use AudioQueueNewInput, which is supposed to be in framework AudioToolbox.  When I add AudioToolbox to my project and try to build, I get warnings to the effect that file /AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox is being ignored because it missing both architectures armv6 and armv7, and errors because the referenced function _AudioQueueNewInput is not defined.

If I remove the framework, I just get the undefined symbol errors.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, by comparing with Apple's "Speak Here" demo app.  I had used a path to a 2009 version of the toolbox to add it to the project, whereas I needed a path to the March 6, 2011 version.